# Completing a SQL query with numbers taken from a list using powershell

Tags: powershell

I run a SQL query through powershell to generate the following text file with 3 columns and data underneath. It looks like this:-

```
PurchaseOrderID PONumMaster DivisionNum    

1234            5678        9871
```

Now, I have a SQL query which needs to be run using these data, which I now do manually

```
insert into  BuyerWorksheetCentralRepository.[po].[PurchaseOrderMessage] 
values (1234 #(This is the value from PurchaseOrderID column)# , 4, 'Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message', getdate(), 'deb00535')
```

A fairly easy task, but since that list generally contains 100s of number and for all of those I need to copy the above line and change the number.

Can I work using PowerShell to take one number from that line each and create the script line with the PurhaseOrderID number in it?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `Import-Csv`

Comment: Hi Marsze, I can do import csv and add --content, but I do not know how to do that for say 50 rows of numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty straightforward. Import the CSV, define a parameterized INSERT SQL query, then loop through the CSV and execute the statement for each row.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is just loop through each value with `ForEach` and insert your rows one at a time. It looks like this using `Invoke-SQLcmd`:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'c:\path\to\file.csv'

Foreach ($row in $csv) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.\SQL' -Database DB01 -Query "INSERT
    into  BuyerWorksheetCentralRepository.[po].[PurchaseOrderMessage] 
    values (
        $($row.PurchaseOrderID), 
        4, 
        'Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message', 
        getdate(), 
        'deb00535'
    )"
}
```

To do a *single* insert with all your data, you may want to use something like the `SqlServer` module's `Write-SqlTableData` command to write a whole object:

```
# Create our own table. 
$rows = $csv | Foreach {
    # Use your actual column names.
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        id=''
        Col1=$_.PurchaseOrderID
        Col2=4
        Col3='Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message'
        Col4='getdate()'
        Col5='deb00535'
    }
}

# $rows now looks like this:
id Col1 Col2 Col3                                                   Col4      Col5    
-- ---- ---- ----                                                   ----      ----    
   1111    4 Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message getdate() deb00535
   2222    4 Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message getdate() deb00535
   3333    4 Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message getdate() deb00535
   4444    4 Timeout waiting for mainframe to send response message getdate() deb00535

# We can write $rows directly into the table
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance '.\SQL' -DatabaseName DB01 -SchemaName dbo `
    -TableName 'BuyerWorksheetCentralRepository.[po].[PurchaseOrderMessage]' `
    -InputData $rows
```

Here's a very detailed walkthrough with more examples: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4627/new-powershell-cmdlets-to-read-and-write-sql-server-tables/

Comment: I tried to do the invoke-sqlcmd but am getting below error

Comment: I tried to do the invoke-sqlcmd but am getting below error


WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

Comment: @ChayanChakraborty `1.` that's just how PowerShell responds when the header row in a CSV file includes a null or empty value, so it may not matter. `2.` the sql commands are part of the `SqlServer` module. Either install that or use what you have available.

Comment: Update, I have tried to install SQLSERVER module but seems like my server is unable to do so. However I am able to run SQL queries but not insert actions. Any help will be greatly appreciated to work this out without the SQLSERVER module.